# href link in footer not working

Tags: html, href

I can't seem to figure out why my links aren't working. I've tried removing title, class and target to make it super simple but I keep getting the same error. Here's the code:

```
<footer>
  <ul id="footer">
    <li>
      <a href=“https://www.twitter.com/MalorieCasimir/ "title="Twitter" class="footer" target="_blank">Malorie's Twitter</a>
      </li>
    <li>
      <a href=“https://www.facebook.com/malorielovestosing/” title="Facebook" class="footer" target="_blank">Malorie's Facebook</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  </footer>
```

When I click it in google chrome, it says my file is not found and it may have been moved or deleted. When I click it in repl.it I get this:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to replit-
repls/webhost-3d7a122e-6922-46d6-bed3-
024190818e3f/“https://www.twitter.com/MalorieCasimir/"title="Twitter".
</Details>
</Error>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` on the `href` of the first link.  And both of your `href`s are using "smart-quotes", change them to normal double quotes.

Comment: the quotes are rather messed up in Twitter href, you might want to read the error to see what is attempting to be called and compare it to what you want to be called.

Comment: Thanks so much! It was the pesky "smart-quotes". Not sure how I even typed those as I didn't even know of their existence up until now...

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with the quotes `"`

```
<footer>
  <ul id="footer">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com/MalorieCasimir/" title="Twitter" class="footer" target="_blank">Malorie's Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/malorielovestosing/" title="Facebook" class="footer" target="_blank">Malorie's Facebook</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```